# PHP error: bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have this error, I can't figure out whats wrong:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home1/tony1964/public_html/2v2tournaments/action.php`

**register.php:**

```
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] === "2") {
            echo '<form class="register_form" action="action.php?do=reg_type_2" method="post"><br>';
            echo 'Team Name*: <input type="text" name="teamname" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Region*: <input type="text" name="teamregion" maxlength="4" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Leader*: <input type="text" name="teamleader" maxlength="16" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Member[1]*: <input type="text" name="teammember" maxlength="16" required /><br>';
            echo '<input name="register_submit" type="submit" value="Register" /><br>';
            echo '</form><br>';
        }
        else if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] === "3") {
            echo '<form class="register_form" action="action.php?do=reg_type_3" method="post"><br>';
            echo 'Team Name*: <input type="text" name="teamname" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Region*: <input type="text" name="teamregion" maxlength="4" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Leader*: <input type="text" name="teamleader" maxlength="16" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Member[1]*: <input type="text" name="teammember1" maxlength="16" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Member[2]*: <input type="text" name="teammember2" maxlength="16" required /><br>';
            echo '<input name="register_submit" type="submit" value="Register" /><br>';
            echo '</form><br>';
        }
        else if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] === "5") {
            echo '<form class="register_form" action="action.php?do=reg_type_5" method="post"><br>';
            echo 'Team Name*: <input type="text" name="teamname" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Region*: <input type="text" name="teamregion" maxlength="4" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Leader*: <input type="text" name="teamleader" maxlength="16" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Member[1]*: <input type="text" name="teammember1" maxlength="16" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Member[2]*: <input type="text" name="teammember2" maxlength="16" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Member[3]*: <input type="text" name="teammember3" maxlength="16" required /><br>';
            echo 'Team Member[4]*: <input type="text" name="teammember4" maxlength="16" required /><br>';
            echo '<input name="register_submit" type="submit" value="Register" /><br>';
            echo '</form><br>';
        }
        else {echo "Error: Incorrect Reg_type";}
    ?>
```

**action.php:**

```
            <?php
            $con=new mysqli("192.185.4.166","myName","myPassword","myDatabase");

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }

            if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] === "reg_type_2") {
                $teamname = $_POST["teamname"];
                $teamregion = $_POST["teamregion"];
                $teamleader = $_POST["teamleader"];
                $teammember = $_POST["teammember"];
                $wins = 0;
                $loses = 0;

                $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `team_type_2` (`teamname`,`region`,`teamleader`,`teammember`,`wins`,`loses`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $teamname, $teamregion, $teamleader, $teammember, $wins, $loses);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
            else if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] === "reg_type_3") {
                $teamname = $_POST["teamname"];
                $teamregion = $_POST["teamregion"];
                $teamleader = $_POST["teamleader"];
                $teammember1 = $_POST["teammember1"];
                $teammember2 = $_POST["teammember2"];
                $wins = 0;
                $loses = 0;

                $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `team_type_3` (`teamname`,`region`,`teamleader`,`teammember1`,`teammember2`,`wins`,`loses`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $teamname, $teamregion, $teamleader, $teammember1, $teammember2, $wins, $loses);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
            else if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] === "reg_type_5") {
                $teamname = $_POST["teamname"];
                $teamregion = $_POST["teamregion"];
                $teamleader = $_POST["teamleader"];
                $teammember1 = $_POST["teammember1"];
                $teammember2 = $_POST["teammember2"];
                $teammember3 = $_POST["teammember3"];
                $teammember4 = $_POST["teammember4"];
                $wins = 0;
                $loses = 0;

                $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `team_type_5` (`teamname`,`region`,`teamleader`,`teammember1`,`teammember2`,`teammember3`,`teammember4`,`wins`,`loses`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $teamname, $teamregion, $teamleader, $teammember1, $teammember2, $teammember3, $teammember4, $wins, $loses);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
            else {echo "Error: Unknown, Contact Admin";}
        ?>
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Please do error checking, you are getting that error because $stmt is not an object so prepare() is returning false due to an error

Comment: It may be that your connection is not being established. You should always check that your connection is working (and never put actual account information online).

Comment: @Floris Yeah just noticed it - thanks for the edit aha.

Comment: @Night Too late, because it is in the version history…

Comment: @Night - people with editing privileges can see the original. Change your password. Now.

Comment: @feeela done and done.

Comment: So what is needed to be done for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in some of your prepare statements.

please change your 3  `$stmt = $con->prepare(...)` to this:

```
if (!($stmt  = $con->prepare("....")) || !is_object($stmt)) {
    die( "Error preparing: (" .$con->errno . ") " . $con->error);
}
```

Comment: Okay I'll try this. I'll let you know how it goes when its done!

Comment: double checked perms, needed updating - now i get `Error preparing: () 
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home1/####/public_html/2v2tournaments/action.php on line 40`

Comment: but if you get that error means that $stmt is not an object, so you sould get into the echo "error preparing..." line. Didnt you?
Look at the update. PLease, use this code everywhere you use $con->prepare

Comment: updated: `Error preparing: (1054) Unknown column 'region' in 'field list'`

Comment: there you have the error! in your table there isnt a region field! please check that out!

Comment: :O thanks for the help!! I am(was) 100% sure everything was right :O